# MySqlDataAdapter UpdateCommand not recognizing primary key

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using a temporary table to display data in a datagridview. When the data in the datagridview is edited, I am trying to update the temporary table. This is the code inside the dataGridView1_RowValidated method that I'm using to do so:

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from     all_plants_temp", con);
                MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
                adapter.Update(changes);
                ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
```

However, I am running into the following error whenever I leave the edited  row:

> Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

From what the error suggests (along with every website I visited), I need to include a primary key in the table. However, I already have an int auto-incrementing primary key. This is the code that I used to create the temporary table, along with the relevant code of the original non-temporary table.

```
ALTER TABLE all_plants ADD COLUMN plantID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE all_plants_temp SELECT * FROM all_plants;
```

Can someone tell me the fault in my code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert with MySQL but I would guess the temporary table doesn't contain the same schema and thus doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: Is there any way to check this? I'm still relatively new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before I belive your temporary table does not have a primary key.
Try using this query. It will create the temporary table with a `Primary Key`. Change `YourPk` with what you want.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE all_plants_temp
(YourPk int(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (YourPk)) SELECT * from all_plants;
```

Comment: This seems to be working (I can't be sure since I have an error that may be related, but most likely isn't). Thank you!